# can I rearrange the keys on a das keyboard from QWERTY to Dvorak?

Tags: keyboard, dvorak, qwerty

I hate to ask this here, but many people on stackoverflow have talked about the Das.

I want to get the version with the printed keys - and since they don't sell a printed key version already set up for Dvorak, I hoped to rearrange the keys myself.

OK, I know that I *can*, but...

my dell sk-8115 keyboard did not manage the conversion from qwerty to dvorak gracefully since keys on different rows are different shapes/heights/angles.

Unfortunately, I can not find any information that tells me if the key blocks are shaped differently on different rows - and das keyboard support has not been back in touch with me.

Comment: I would suggest you not change the keys. The reason is so you are not tempted to look down. I can say this from experience. I used dvorak only. When I switched I did a hard switch. I just forced myself to learn the keyboard from a little printout. I am now very proficient on dvorak. I've just purchased the DAS ultimate silent with no key markings to learn the keyboard even better. Mainly for the special characters on the number keys.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was finally able to reach support @ das keyboards and now have the official answer.

They said:

> All of our key-caps have the same
>   height as well as the same symmetry
>   and therefore will not lead to
>   staggered keys.  Nevertheless, if you
>   want to rearrange the key-caps, this
>   will void your keyboard warranty.
>   (please refer to our manual on our
>   website.)

Voiding the warranty seems harsh, especially considering how easily the key-caps are removed (seen in a youtube video), but I think it's going to be worth it.

Hopefully someone will find this useful.

Comment: This doesn't apply to the Ultimate keyboards (which came out after this answer was written); each row has a different curvature and changing them around makes things more uncomfortable.

Comment: The Ultimate keyboards have blank keycaps though, so there's no reason to re-arrange them anyway